# sum of two variables in django

Tags: django

I am trying to get the sum of 'a' and 'b' and display it with each post. But I am getting the error - 'Count' object has no attribute 'split'. Can someone please help. Thanks

```
def get_queryset(self):
    a = Count('blogger__posts__title')
    b = Count('blogger__posts__likes')

   return (Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
                                    .order_by('-date')
                                    .annotate(score=Sum(F(a)+F(b),output_field=FloatField()))
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as below

```
def get_queryset(self):
    a = Count('blogger__posts__title')
    b = Count('blogger__posts__likes')
    return (Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
        .order_by('-date')
        .annotate(s1=a, s2=b)
        .annotate(score=Sum(F('s1')+F('s2'),output_field=FloatField()))
        )
```